# Can't find place to create a dataset with trial account

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm using the $300 trial account to play with google bigquery.  I am the project owner.

I want to save a view, which requires creating a dataset.

I found this link (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/datasets) which shows a "WEBUI" tab where you get access to do that, but I can't find the page/link that shows the "WEBUI" link when I am logged in.

I checked the permissions of my role, and it has the apparent permissions needed to be able to create a dataset.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Web UI for Google BigQuery can be accessed via this URL: https://console.cloud.google.com/bigquery

Once you are in, make sure you have the correct project selected (using the dropdown menu at the top) before creating your datasets, tables, and views.

Comment: thanks - I was there - but this time I realized that I needed to click my project name over in the bottom left near where the other public dataset was - clicked it and it showed the "Add Dataset" option.  I had been looking at the stuff in the upper left where there was a dropdown arrow for the "Google Dashboard".  Had hoped it was something silly on my part and it was.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

BigQuery has two WebUIs:

- https://console.cloud.google.com
- https://bigquery.cloud.google.com

you can create with both datasets.